# In which coordinate space should the vertex be passed to fragment shader?

Tags: opengl-es, coordinates, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am clipping off on the fragment shader (setting the transparency to 0/1) based on the cut off vertex (*v_cutPos*) and the current vertex (*v_currPos*) that I get from the vertex shader. These two vertices are passed as *world coords*.

Now, the cut off logic works fine. But the cut itself is not smooth (it has to follow a certain shape). And when I pass the same vertices after converting to *clip space*, the cut is much smoother (or finer.)

Is there any explanation to this?

**//fragment shader**

```
precision highp float;                                                     
varying mediump vec4 v_color;                                              
varying vec4 v_currPos;                                                  
varying vec4 v_cutPos;                                                     
                                                                           
/* returns 0 if pt is inside box otherwise 1 */                            
float insideCutArea(vec2 pt, vec2 cutPos)                                
{                                                                          
   return float(pt.y > cutPos.y);                                          
}                                                                          
                                                                           
void main(void)                                                            
{                                                                          
    float transparency = insideCutArea(v_currPos.xy, v_cutPos.xy);  
    gl_FragColor = vec4(v_color.xyz, v_color.w * transparency);            
}
```

**//vertex shader**

```
varying mediump vec4 v_color; 
uniform vec3 cutPos;
varying vec4 v_currPos;                                                  
varying vec4 v_cutPos; 
void main(void)                                                                                  
{                                                                                                
                                           
//-------------------
other transformations 
-------------------//                                  
v_cutPos = myPMVMatrix * vec4(cutPos,1.0); //cut is not fine when not multiplying with the matrix           
gl_Position = myPMVMatrix * vec4(validVertex, 1.0);                                                
v_currPos = myPMVMatrix * vec4(validVertex, 1.0); //cut is not fine when not multiplying with the matrix                                            
v_color = color;                                                                            
                                                                                             
}
```

> PS: This question was previously closed due to not much clarity. I
> have created this again with code explaining what I have done.

Comment: *"In which coordinate space should the vertex be passed to fragment shader?"* - It's up to you and depends on your needs. Usually it is world space or view space.

Comment: Thanks for you response. In that case, why there is a difference between the two? The clip space vertices comparison produces a finer result than with the world space vertices.

Comment: What is a "finer" result? Likely it is a completely wrong result. A clip space coordinate is a [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) and has 4 components. You completely skip the w component and the perspective divide e.g.: `v_cutPos.xy / v_cutPos.w`